# Watson language identification

Tags: ibm-watson

I had implemented the following curl code using RESTSharp to find the language of sentence "What is your name?".

I followed the "Identify language" under : http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/language-translation/api/v2/#identify

```
        string source = "What is your name?";
        string credentials;
        string auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", tuid, tpwd);
        string auth64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
        credentials = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", auth64);

        var langDet = new RestClient(detURL);
        var requestDet = new RestRequest("?text={authToken}",Method.POST);
        requestDet.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(tuid, tpwd);
        requestDet.AddParameter("text", source, ParameterType.UrlSegment); 
        IRestResponse responseDet = langDet.Execute(requestDet);
```

However, when this code is executed I get a list of languages and confidence level while I still am not sure how to accurately specify which language the above sentence goes to. Please help me where I am wrong.

My detUrl variable above is: https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/language-translation/api/v2/identify

Answer (score 1):

you can get what you want using the Alchemy API, which is also available in Bluemix. Here's an example using Java + Watson SDK

```
    AlchemyLanguage service = new AlchemyLanguage();
    service.setApiKey("XXXXXXXXX");

    Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TEXT, "What is your name?");

    Language language = service.getLanguage(params);
    System.out.println(language);
```

I use this Java SDK above, but there's a .NET port for it here

https://github.com/dennyboy/WatsonCSharp

Answer (score 0):

Thank you !

I found the answer.

(1) In my code above, I have been passing the {authtoken} instead of the string I had wanted to send (string source in example below

```
var requestDet = new RestRequest("?text=" + source, Method.POST);
```

(2) Once done, I had to deserialize the output from "responseDet" and filter the first value (as below). I had used Jsonconvert class.

```
DataSet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(responseDet.Content);
            return data.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

My code is working fine. Thanks for your help !